# Nexus 9, no recovery, no USB debugging, OEM locked in Settings

Tags: fastboot, bootloader, bootloader-lock, nexus-9

I've got a pretty complex problem.

### At the moment:

- Nexus 9 WiFi Tablet, USB Debugging not enabled
- Normal Startup: Android laying on the floor
- Startup with <kbd>Power</kbd>+<kbd>Volume Down</kbd>:

  - Fastboot Bootloader LOCKED
  - Recovery doesn't start
  - Factory Reset crashes as well
- `fastboot oem unlock` → `permission denied`

### Question

I want to know whether I can completely reset/wipe my device through fastboot or whatever I can use to do it.

I am not able to `fastboot boot boot.img` or something similar because USB Debugging and OEM unlocking aren't enabled and I can't start the device to do so.

The device has no microSD card slot.

EDIT:
When I choose `HBOOT` → `RECOVERY` I get the Android laying on the floor with a red triangle.

It is the device of a colleague of mine. He restarted the tablet and it happened. Don't have more information.

[**SOLUTION**]:

I could find a solution for my problem.

`adb.exe sideload volantis-ota....zip`

With the help of an OTA-Image, I could reset and recover the tablet.

Comment: I also have a Nexus 9, what's your Android version? And forgive me for asking, but how did you manage to get it into this sorry state? Please [edit] these pieces of info into the question.

Comment: What do you mean Recovery doesn't start? What happens when you choose Recovery mode from bootloader?

Comment: When I choose "HBOOT" -->"RECOVERY" I get the Android laying on the floor with a red triangle.

Comment: Try pressing 'Power' and 'Volume Up' for a few seconds, that should allow recovery to start.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=60713211&postcount=17